Yield not change local variable in streaming
full_answer = ""
total_tokens = 0
conversation_id = None
def generate_stream():
    nonlocal total_tokens, full_answer
    global conversation_id
    current_response = ""
    for chunk in answer_stream:
        if (
            hasattr(chunk, "usage_metadata")
            and chunk.usage_metadata is not None
        ):
            total_tokens = chunk.usage_metadata.get("total_tokens", 0)
        if hasattr(chunk, "content") and chunk.content:
            current_response += chunk.content
            yield chunk.content
    current_response = current_response.strip()
    full_answer = current_response
    conversation_id = self.store_message(
        {
            "message": full_answer,
            "chat_conversation_id": chat_conversation_id,
            "tokens_used": total_tokens,
        }
    )
    print(conversation_id)
return generate_stream, conversation_id

// Route 

@search_bp.route("/search", methods=["POST"])
def searchQuery(id):
    data = request.get_json()

    try:
        result_stream, id = search_service.search(data)

        return app.response_class(
            stream_with_context(result_stream()), content_type="application/json", headers={"x-conversation-id": id}
        )

    except Exception as e:
        return error_helper(str(e), status_code=500)

I send conversation_id but it is None inside the function it is proper integer.
When I access inside then it works but in headers it was None.
I want to pass Id into next function.

nonlocal should only be used in nested functions. In a top-level function, use global to refer to global variables.

The return statement needs to be indented so it's inside the function definition.

How do you call generate_stream()? You don't set conversation_id until after the loop is done.

Why is the function returning itself as one of the values?

I using streaming so in Flask Streaming we need to pass function so i return function.
